# I want to do OAuth authentication for Twitter using Firebase Cloud Functions and passport-twitter, but it times out

Tags: typescript, firebase, twitter, oauth, google-cloud-functions

I want to create an authentication server that fetches access tokens of authorized users from consumer keys and consumer secrets in order to manipulate Twitter accounts that I have allowed to authenticate my application.

I wrote the following code in Firebase CloudFunctions to accomplish my goal, but it times out and I can't see the Twitter authentication page.

What I've done

- Verified that Consumer Key is set as an environment variable.
- Verified that Consumer Secret is set as an environment variable.
- Upgraded to the Blaze plan.

Are there any settings or areas that might be wrong?

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as passport from "passport";
import * as twitter from "passport-twitter";


// // Start writing Firebase Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
//

require('dotenv').config()

// @ts-ignore
passport.use(new twitter.Strategy({
        consumerKey: process.env['twitter.ck'],
        consumerSecret: process.env['twitter.cs'],
        callbackURL: 'http://127.0.0.1',
        proxy: true
    },
    function(token: any, tokenSecret: any, profile: any, cb: (arg0: null, arg1: any) => any) {
        // In this example, the user's Twitter profile is supplied as the user
        // record.  In a production-quality application, the Twitter profile should
        // be associated with a user record in the application's database, which
        // allows for account linking and authentication with other identity
        // providers.
        console.log(`tkn ${token}`)
        console.log(`tknsec ${tokenSecret}`)
        console.log(`of ${JSON.stringify(profile)}`)
        return cb(null, profile);
    }));
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

export const callback = functions.https.onRequest(((req, resp) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.params));
    resp.send('ok');
}))

export const login = functions.https.onRequest(((req, resp) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.params));
    console.log(`ck: ${ process.env['twitter.ck']}`);
    console.log(`cs: ${ process.env['twitter.cs']}`);

    return passport.authenticate('twitter');

}))
```

Comment: my request always
always returns 
`login
Function execution took 60003 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'`

Comment: Did you [search for that error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=Function+execution+took+60003+ms%2C+finished+with+status%3A+%27timeout%27) yet? It is quite common.

Comment: I'm already searching for error messages.. In this source code, the `passport.authenticate('twitter I'm hoping that the ')` line will redirect me to the Twitter authentication page, but in fact I'm wondering about the lack of redirection to

Comment: passport.authenticate('twitter')